# Optimize mysql query over multiple tables, using IN vs JOIN (or other methods) and performance

Tags: mysql

I was told to use joins to optimize this query:

```
select distinct p.product_id 
from cart_products p 
     left join product_bikes b on p.product_id = b.product_id where bike_id = $bike_id
or
p.product_id in (
    select product_id from cart_product_options where option_id in (
        select option_id from cart_product_option_variants where variant_id in (
            select variant_id from variant_bikes where bike_id=$bike_id
        )
    )
)
```

However using joins seems to give no speed boost at all:

```
select distinct p.product_id from cart_products p 
    left join product_bikes pb on p.product_id = pb.product_id and pb.bike_id = $bike_id
    left join cart_product_options po on po.product_id = p.product_id
    left join cart_product_option_variants pov on pov.option_id = po.option_id
    left join variant_bikes vb on vb.variant_id = pov.variant_id and vb.bike_id = $bike_id
    where pb.bike_id = $bike_id or vb.bike_id = $bike_id
```

Depending on server load and current table size they both perform quickly but when there are a lot more products, product options, etc this section of an addon did cause slowdowns.  I just wish to know what way will make mysql run this query quickest.  Can someone say for a fact JOINS is the superior answer or know any other tricks to speed this up?

Comment: Can you verify that all the fields used in the JOIN conditions and WHERE clause have some sort of index defined?

Comment: Yes I can verify that.  All JOIN conditions are on primary keys or indexed otherwise.  The main problem is that product_bikes and variant_bikes even with just 1000 or so items in the store will have over a million rows and we're looking to have over 10,000 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql does a very poor job of handling subqueries in "in" statements.  The use of "exists" with a correlated subquery is much faster, particularly if there is an index on the fields used in the inner table for the correlation.

Try something like:

```
select distinct p.product_id
from cart_products p left join
     product_bikes b
     on p.product_id = b.product_id
where bike_id = $bike_id or
      exists (select *
              from cart_product_options cpo
               where cpo.productid = p.productid and
                     exists (select option_id
                             from cart_product_option_variants cpov
                             where cpo.option_id = cpov.option_id and
                                   exists (select variant_id
                                           from variant_bikes vb
                                           where vb.variant_id = cpov.variant_id and
                                                 bike_id=$bike_id
                                           )
                             )
              )
```

This should work . . . but you do have a lot of nested subqueries.

Comment: Thank you, will this perform better than JOINs or are JOIN the end all?

Comment: It should perform better than the "in".  I suspect the join version has the problem of creating lots of extra rows, because of all the joins between the tables.  In other words, they probably both have bad performance, but for different reasons.